Spaces removed in class option via l3keys
I define a class kv-option via l3keys, as example I use title. If I want to set the title via \documentclass[title = {My first title}]{Testing} it works but whitespaces are removed (Result: "Myfirsttitle", not "My first title").
As I was curious if it would also happen when using a command I created one: \NewDocumentCommand{\Title}{m}{\keys_set:nn{Testing}{title = #1}} to set the key. And voilà it works as intended: \Title{My 2nd super long title} results in "My 2nd super long title".
Now Im wondering: why do whitespaces get removed when setting the title key as class option but not with a command. I set both titles outside of LaTeX3, so LaTeX3s syntax should be off and whitespaces should not be stripped or am I missing something?
MWE:
main.tex
\documentclass[title = {My first title}]{Testing}

\Title{My 2nd super long title}

\begin{document}
    Hallo Welt!
\end{document}

testing.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023-11-01]
\ProvidesExplClass{Testing}{2024-05-31}{1}{}

\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

\keys_define:nn{Testing}{
    title .code:n = {
        \ClassWarningNoLine{DEBUG}{#1}
    },
}

\ProcessKeysOptions{Testing}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Title}{m}{\keys_set:nn{Testing}{title = #1}}

% Code below: Minimal.cls

\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8in}

\pagenumbering{arabic}  % but no page numbers are printed because:
\pagestyle{empty}       % this is actually already in the kernel

Update/Addition:
I try to learn LaTeX3 by looking at others code and trying to understand it. In the package fnpct the author defines package constants like the package version, data, etc. So I thought, why not define the package name once as a string constant (\str_const:Nn \c_module_name_str {Classname}) and use it throughout the whole package/class at various places (using the programming principle "Don't repeat yourself"), e.g., \ProcessKeysOptions {fnpct} -> \ProcessKeysOptions {\str:use:N \c_module_name_str}in fnpct or in fontspec-luatex.sty \msg_new:nnx {fontspec} {#1} { ^^J \tl_trim_spaces:n {#2} } -> \msg_new:nnx {\str:use:N \c_module_name_str} {#1} { ^^J \tl_trim_spaces:n {#2} }. It works fine for \ProcessKeysOptions{str:use:N \c_module_name_str}, but as I tried it with your solution \ProcessKeyOptions [str:use:N \c_module_name_str] it resulted in a warning that the key was unused even when defined in \documentclass[]{}. So I tried expanding it (1. \exp_args:Ne \ProcessKeyOptions [ \str_use:N \c_module_name_str ] -> results in an error, 2. \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \ProcessKeyOptions [ \str_use:N \c_module_name_str ] -> results in the warning "LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [title]"). Sadly, your approach does not work for me either; I still get the warning that "title" is an unused global option.
Below the updated cls file with all tried version:
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_const:Nn \c_Testing_Classname_str { Testing }

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023-11-01]
\ProvidesExplClass{\str_use:N \c_Testing_Classname_str}{2024-05-31}{1}{}

% \RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

\keys_define:nn{\str_use:N \c_Testing_Classname_str}{
    title .code:n = {
        \ClassWarningNoLine{DEBUG}{#1}
    },
}

% \ProcessKeysOptions{Testing} % works

% \def\abc{Testing} % LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [title].
% \ProcessKeyOptions[\abc]

% \edef\abc{Testing} % LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [title].
% \ProcessKeyOptions[\abc]

% \ProcessKeyOptions[\str_use:N \c_Testing_Classname_str] % LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [title].

% \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \ProcessKeyOptions[\str_use:N \c_Testing_Classname_str] % LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [title].

% \exp_args:Ne \ProcessKeyOptions[\str_use:N \c_Testing_Classname_str] % LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

\NewDocumentCommand{\Title}{m}{\keys_set:nn{\str_use:N \c_Testing_Classname_str}{title = #1}}

% Code below: Minimal.cls

\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8in}

\pagenumbering{arabic}  % but no page numbers are printed because:
\pagestyle{empty}       % this is actually already in the kernel


Use siunitx.sty for an example of expl3 usage. It's intended to be maintained as an exemplar.

If you want to expand to the value of a variable which should be an optional argument you can use \exp_args:NNV \ProcessKeyOptions [ \c_module_name_str ] or \exp_last_unbraced:NNV \ProcessKeyOptions [ \c_module_name_str ] (the former will expand to \ProcessKeyOptions[{<name>}], the latter to \ProcessKeyOptions[<name>]). Note that you have to tell expl3 that you want to leave the single token [ unchanged and unbraced (N).

This is a feature (\zap@space) of the classic latex option processing.
The original l3keys package code builds off that and the space has already gone.
The version that is built in to the format uses a separate "raw" option list that is made available by current latex and so has access to the space. There are some minor changes notably the command no longer has an s in the name and the key family is optional (defaulting to the package name).
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023-11-01]
\ProvidesExplClass{Testing}{2024-05-31}{1}{}

%\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

\keys_define:nn{Testing}{
    title .code:n = {
        \ClassWarningNoLine{DEBUG}{#1}
    },
}

%\ProcessKeysOptions{Testing}
 \ProcessKeyOptions[Testing]

\NewDocumentCommand{\Title}{m}{\keys_set:nn{Testing}{title = #1}}

% Code below: Minimal.cls

\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8in}

\pagenumbering{arabic}  % but no page numbers are printed because:
\pagestyle{empty}       % this is actually already in the kernel


logs:
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-05-08>
(./Testing.cls
Document Class: Testing 2024-05-31 v1 

Class DEBUG Warning: My first title.

)

Class DEBUG Warning: My 2nd super long title.


Is it possible to use variables within \ProcessKeyOptions' optional argument, like so: \ProcessKeyOptions[ \c_my_string_str ]?

@Dave yes you could easily have tested: \def\abc{Testing}\ProcessKeyOptions[\abc] works (but why would you want that?)

I updated my post due to limited character space in comments

@Dave \def\abc{Testing}\ProcessKeyOptions[\abc] works in an up to date tl2024, what release do you have?

@DavidCarlisle You don't get a warning about unused global options?

@DavidCarlisle As of the post update I was using LuaHBTeX 1.18.1 via MiKTeX 24.4 (format=lualatex 2024.6.2) with LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1 and L3 programming layer <2024-04-11>. After checking for updates, Im now running This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.1 (MiKTeX 24.4) (format=lualatex 2024.6.2) with LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1 and L3 programming layer <2024-05-08> but the warning remains in the log with your approach ("LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [title].").

odd, that's the latest latex release.  I'll check later mine (I may have some local code affecting things:-) but go with cfr in the meantime @Dave

If you really want to do this, you can generate appropriate forms of the control sequences which you use to define and set keys so that the module name is specified as the value of a variable (V) rather than as the unmodified contents of a braced argument (n).
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Testing.cls}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_const:Nn \c_Testing_Classname_str { Testing }

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023-11-01]
\ProvidesExplClass{\str_use:N \c_Testing_Classname_str}{2024-05-31}{1}{}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_define:nn { Vn }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_set:nn { Vn }

\keys_define:Vn \c_Testing_Classname_str
{
  title .code:n = {
    \ClassWarningNoLine{DEBUG}{#1}
  },
}


\ProcessKeyOptions[\str_use:N \c_Testing_Classname_str] % LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [title].


\NewDocumentCommand{\Title}{m}{
  \keys_set:Vn \c_Testing_Classname_str {title = #1}
}


\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8in}

\pagenumbering{arabic}  % but no page numbers are printed because:
\pagestyle{empty}       % this is actually already in the kernel
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[title = {My first title}]{Testing}
\Title{My 2nd super long title}
\begin{document}
  a 
\end{document}

produces
(./Testing.cls
Document Class: Testing 2024-05-31 v1

Class DEBUG Warning: My first title.

)

Class DEBUG Warning: My 2nd super long title.

